How to do Blazor WASM (Client) initialization from a configuration file of some sort
All,
We have a bunch of WASM components that run on the client. They use HttpClient to post requests to the server. The HTTP Client requires BaseAddress of the server. We need to initialize the BaseAddress in Program.cs that executes on the client from configuration file (ex settings.json). This is required obviously because each client installation will have different server URL. What's the best way to achieve this?
Remember, this initialization code runs on the client, at which point the Server URL must be set.
Maybe is there away to have .net download setings.json (when downloading wasm runtime/dlls) to the client and read it in the Program.cs file logic?

What's wrong with appsettings.json placed in the wwwroot folder?

Please read my original post carefully. In order to get appsettings.json, it sits on the server, and you need http client to download it. But http client doesn't know the url to the server, because it wasn't set yet. It is a catch 22 scenario.

No you can put it in the wwwroot folder of your client project if it does not have one create it.

@BrianParker So you're saying, I can add appsettings.json in wwwroot and then initialize my server using this line:  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["FrontendUrl"] in Program.cs and it will read the FrontendUrl property?

in your client program.cs yes.

Yeap, that worked, thanks. I was not aware that wwwroot folder had another appsetttings.json that gets downloaded and used in Program.cs.

AppSettings.json placed in wwwroot folder of the WASM project
{
  "ServerBaseURl":  "http://localhost:5000"
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

        var baseUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServerBaseURl") 
            ?? throw new Exception("Unable to read ServerBaseURl..");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}



Thanks Brian. I was not aware of the wwwroot folder containing appsettings.json that would be used by Program.cs

Use wwwroot/appsettings.json file. Configuration in there gets loaded in Program.cs on the client side as commented by community.
